# Cant see remote webRTC streams in multiple concurrent sessions in firefox

Tags: webrtc

https://simplewebrtc.com/demo.html

if i create room and open this demo in 4 tabs in firefox 49
last user can't see remote stream

Same in my own project

Answer (score 0):

works fine here. Have you clicked "create room" and are using the same room url in each tab?